# Трассировка стека вызовов при нажатии комбинации клавиш Ctrl+C, Ctrl+D и тд

Tags: c++, linux, отладка, стек, трассировка

Всем добрый вечер. Заинтересовался таким вопросом-возможно ли как то получить стек пройденных функций при нажатии комбинации клавиш *Ctrl+C(SIGINT), Ctrl+D*?

Работаю в *ОС Linux* SL7 имеется большой объем кода, написанного на языке *С++*.
Данный вопрос пришел ко мне в голову из-за следующей ситуации: отлаживаю свою программу на большом примере, который в различный момент может подвисать, и подвисать надолго.

Ожидание завершения работы программы при запуске исполняемого файла с режимом *Debug* будет уморительным, тк слишком много времени я потеряю на инициализации всех своих параметров в программе и объявлении массивов, расчёта некоторых арифметических функций и тд. В общем, debug мне не подойдет для отладки.
Погуглив, нашел на просторах интернета хороший трассировщик "*backward*", он мне помогает в некоторых моментах.

Собственно, прошу совета у знающих людей, возможно ли выплюнуть трассировку стека вызовов пройденных функций при нажатии соответствующих клавиш. Заранее, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Странный вопрос. ¿Что-то мешает посмотреть стек вызов в любой момент в отладчике? "Сборка исполняемого файла с режимом Debug будет уморительным" - ¿Шта?

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть стек вызов в отладчике, как я предполагаю, нужно, чтобы моя программа завершила работу.
а у меня происходит зависание программы
Сама сборка в дебажном режиме, понятное дело, не будет уморительным(отредактирую свой вопрос). Именно процесс завершения работы программы в несколько раз  замедлится, а у меня  тем более зависание происходит. Как отладить ума не приложу

Comment: Ну пост-мортем отладчики тоже бывают, однако обычный сферический gdb без проблем позволяет смотреть стек вызовов, когда захочется. ¿Вы что, никогда не пользовались отладчиком?

Comment: Я знаю что такое gdb. Не часто пользовался им, но всё же знаком. То есть gdb позволит мне посмотреть трассировку при зависании? Если да, то спасибо, попробую с ним поработать.
Прочитайте вопрос, который я описал выше - Можно ли вывести стек при нажатии комбинации клавиш.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes